# Hibernate criteria setFetchMode gets ignored using projections

Tags: hibernate, fetch, criteria, hibernate-criteria, nhibernate-projections

Im trying to eagerly fetch all contentItems to avoid the N + 1 lazy initialization problem but my setfetchmode call gets ignored by hibernate when using projections. While not using projections it works as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

The contentItem is a custom object.

```
Session session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Media.class);
    criteria
        .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
          .add(Projections.property("id"), "id")
          .add(Projections.property("fileName"), "fileName")
          .add(Projections.property("mimeType"), "mimeType")
          .add(Projections.property("contentItem"), "contentItem"))
        .setFetchMode("contentItem", FetchMode.JOIN)
        .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Media.class));
    criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("id"));
    criteria.setFirstResult(firstResult);
    criteria.setMaxResults(maxResults);
    return criteria.list();
```

UPDATE: In addition to @NiVeR answer

Entity relationship fetch type still has not effect on outcome.

```
private ContentItem contentItem;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "content_item_id")
public ContentItem getContentItem() {
    return this.contentItem;
}
```

And repositioning the setFetchMode like this also has no effect.

```
Session session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Media.class);
criteria.setFetchMode("contentItem", FetchMode.JOIN);
criteria
    .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
      .add(Projections.property("id"), "id")
      .add(Projections.property("fileName"), "fileName")
      .add(Projections.property("mimeType"), "mimeType")
      .add(Projections.property("contentItem"), "contentItem"))
    .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Media.class));
criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("id"));
criteria.setFirstResult(firstResult);
criteria.setMaxResults(maxResults);
return criteria.list();
```

Comment: So, if you remove the projections it works? It doesn't give the n+1 problem?

Comment: Exactly, it does not give the n+1 problem when removing the projections.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the behavior is explained by the line:

```
.add(Projections.property("contentItem"), "contentItem"))
```

at this point to project the relation of this entity, Hibernate uses the FetchType defined in the entity where you defined the relation. So the FetchMode.JOIN that you add afterwards has no impact because it happens later.

Comment: I have tried adding the setfetchmode at an early state but it does not have an effect and the fetchType defined in the entity is eager fetch. I will edit with the entity and its relation. But thanks!

Comment: Another point is that the projection should be done after the join is made.

Comment: See updated. Still no effect. It still gets ignored somehow.

Comment: @Merv You shouldn't use `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)` on entity level because you can fall into huge entity graph loading. You should leave it LAZY there, and use a query (as you are doing) to override the join type just for that specific query because you know that you want to load all data.

Comment: I tried with putting it to @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) but still the same. It still gives me this hibernate query: Hibernate: select this_.id as y0_, this_.file_name as y1_, this_.mime_type as y2_, this_.content_item_id as y3_ from development.media this_ order by y0_ asc limit ? . Still no join as I should expect.